# Stored procedure (Input vs Output) vs Return - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and I recently studied about stored procedures.

I want to know when should you use an input or an output stored procedure and how is it different from return. Also when do you prefer to use return over stored procedures.

I am unable to find the specific answer a layman's guide would be really thankful.

I only know

- When you want to return one or more items with a data type then it is better to use an output parameter.
- Generally, use an output parameter for anything that needs to be returned.
- When you want to return only one item with only an integer data type then it is better to use a return value.
- Generally, the return value is only to inform success or failure of the stored procedure.
- A return List item a value of 0 indicates success and any non-zero value indicates failure.

Comment: When you say return function, do you mean `RETURN` statement? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) calls out that should only be used to indicate success or failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple, actually:

- Use input parameters to send data into the stored procedure.
- Use Output parameters to return scalar values from the stored procedure.
- Use a `Select` statement inside the procedure to return tabular data.
- Don't use `Return`.<sup>1</sup> If you want to abort a stored procedure mid-process, throw an error instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, it depends on the client, but usually, it's simpler to use errors than return codes, and also safer. There is no guarantee that the client will actually bother to check the return code, but if you throw an error, that can't be ignored.

However, there are probably a few times when it's better to return a number other than zero to indicate failure, but that means that whatever code that is using the procedure must be aware of the meaning of the numbers, which often leads to a terrible mess.

I once worked for a company that used this kind of thing, and I inherited a c# code containing an `enum` of approximately 300 members, all for error codes thrown from stored procedures - which means that every new error in any stored procedure we had to first make sure that error is not already in the enum, and if it's not, we had to recompile the c# code and re-deploy it even if we only changed an existing procedure.
Naturally, this was a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Yes.  Never use return codes for the client.  They were only ever intended for TSQL code to manage control flow, and now they are obsolete since TRY/CATCH.